# SQL - selecting last row ordered by a date

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL:

```
"SELECT users.username, users.id_user, friends.name, friends.meet_date 
 FROM users INNER JOIN friends ON (users.id_user = friends.id_user) 
 GROUP BY username ORDER BY username";
```

This is the output on my webpage:

```
Username    Friend's Name    Meeting Date
George      Nicolas          2010
Man         Anatol           2008
```

For now, it selects just the first rows from database for each user.

Each table has an auto_increment, id_user for the first table and id_friend for the second one.

I would like it to show that friend which were meet last by each user.

I've tried to add an `order by "meet_date DESC"` but it doesn't work.

How could I achieve my wish?

Comment: if meet_date is a date/time stamp, why aren't you storing that as a real datetime field? That'd let you sort by the date, not the string value of the date.

Comment: I've changed it to a datetime and my ordering by "meet_date DESC" still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is a subquery:

```
 SELECT 
   users.username, 
   users.id_user, 
   ( select friends.name  
     from friends 
     where (users.id_user = friends.id_user) 
     ORDER BY friends.meet_date desc
     LIMIT 1 ) as friend_name,       
   ( select friends.meet_date
     from friends 
     where (users.id_user = friends.id_user) 
     ORDER BY friends.meet_date desc
     LIMIT 1 ) as friend_meet_date
 FROM users 
 ;
```

*** Testing ***

```
create table users (username varchar(50), id_user int);
create table friends ( name varchar(50), id_user int, meet_date int);

insert into users values ( 'a', 1),('b',2);
insert into friends values ('c', 1, 0), ('d',1,1);
```

Results:

```
| USERNAME | ID_USER | FRIEND_NAME | FRIEND_MEET_DATE |
-------------------------------------------------------
|        a |       1 |           d |                1 |
|        b |       2 |      (null) |           (null) |
```

[Try it at sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9bcd/1/0).

Notice thant a correlated subquery is not an elegant approach, is the easy approach.

Comment: Why do I get "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"? and the output now on my webpage is empty... Nothing slected?

Comment: Copy this query in phpmyadmin or in mysql console and test it. If the query works it self, post another question with your new issue. If query don't work in phpmyadmin or mysql console, please, edit answer and post new data to isolate poblem.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select friends.name from friends where (users.id_user = friends.id_user) ORDER BY' at line 1 :/

Answer (score 4):

One standard trick is to use an outer self join:

```
 SELECT users.username, users.id_user, friends.name, friends.meet_date 
 FROM users 
 INNER JOIN friends ON (users.id_user = friends.id_user) 
 LEFT JOIN friends f2 ON friends.meet_date > f2.meet_date
 WHERE f2.(primary key) IS NULL
 GROUP BY username
 ORDER BY username
```

which finds the date for which there is no other record with a greater date value. This avoids the inefficiencies of correlated subqueries and extra aggregates; or the doubtful assumption that records are always added in meet-date order which is necessary if you want to use the primary key.

*** Edited by other user ***

You should replace (primary key) by primary key column table or just by a f2 column:

```
SELECT users.username, users.id_user, friends.name, friends.meet_date 
 FROM users 
 left JOIN friends ON (users.id_user = friends.id_user) 
 LEFT JOIN friends f2 ON friends.meet_date > f2.meet_date
 WHERE f2.id_user IS NULL
 GROUP BY username
 ORDER BY username
```

Query runs as spected:

```
| USERNAME | ID_USER |   NAME | MEET_DATE |
-------------------------------------------
|        a |       1 |      c |         0 |
|        b |       2 | (null) |    (null) |
```

Comment: I like this trick. Are you sure that the query with this non equijoin has more performance than a correlate subquery?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(primary key)... This is what I get

Comment: sorry about edit your answer. Your trick seems a very nice approach +1 .

Answer (score 1):

Do you not have an auto_increment field? This would allow you to sort by that. The other option is to change meet_date to a date field so you can properly sort by it. No reason to store a `DateTime` as a `varchar` field

Comment: I've already changed it to a datetime, but what about the second part of Sorting By?

Comment: Yes I have an auto_increment field!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have got `id` as a `primary key` with `auto_increment` in `users` table, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT MAX(users.id), users.username, users.id_user, friends.name, friends.meet_date 
 FROM users INNER JOIN friends ON (users.id_user = friends.id_user) 
 GROUP BY username ORDER BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.username, users.id_user, friends.name, friends.meet_date 
 FROM users INNER JOIN friends ON (users.id_user = friends.id_user) 
 GROUP BY username ORDER BY username
having max(friends.meet_date)=friends.meet_date
```